# MainActivityModule cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have first using dagger2 in android, and I try to reflect my project using the struct same as the `google/iosched`. But when I compile this simple project below, it report the `MainActivityModule` can not be used in it.

```
// MainApplication.kt

class MainApplication : DaggerApplication() {

    ...

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(this)
    }

    ...
}


// AppComponent.kt

@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        ActivityBindingModule::class,
        ViewModelModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MainApplication> {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance application: MainApplication): AppComponent
    }
}


// ActivityBindingModule.kt

@Module
@Suppress("UNUSED")
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(
        modules = [
            // activity
            MainActivityModule::class
        ]
    )
    internal abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity
}


// MainActivity.kt

class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    @Inject lateinit var viewModel: MainActivityModule

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = viewModelProvider(viewModelFactory)
    }
    ...
}


// MainActivityModule.kt

@Module
@Suppress("UNUSED")
abstract class MainActivityModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MainActivityViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun bindViewModel(viewModel: MainActivityViewModel): ViewModel
}


// MainActivityViewModel.kt

class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(

) : ViewModel() {

}
```

The error message below.

```
[Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.app.di.MainActivityModule cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.example.app.MainApplication> {
                ^
      com.example.app.di.MainActivityModule is injected at
          com.example.app.ui.MainActivity.viewModel
      com.example.app.ui.MainActivity is injected at
```

Comment: Can you post detailed error message here or full stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the [iosched example MainActivity.kt:116](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/MainActivity.kt#L116) injects a MainActivity**ViewModel**:

```
private lateinit var viewModel: MainActivityViewModel
```

While you've injected a MainActivity**Module**:

```
@Inject lateinit var viewModel: MainActivityModule
```

A few notes there:

1. Modules are for configuring Dagger: You should never need to inject or refer to *modules* from your ViewModels, Activities, Views, or other classes. You should only interact with Module instances at all *if* you have a Module that isn't an interface or abstract (open) class, and that doesn't have a public no-arg constructor.
2. Despite the fact that you should almost never inject Modules in your graph, Dagger will *allow* you to do so *if and only if* they are bound in your graph. That's how you should read the error message: "com.example.app.di.MainActivityModule cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method"; since you've asked for a MainActivityModule via `@Inject` and Dagger does not know how to provide one, it throws this compile-time exception.
3. Note that iosched's MainActivity.kt does not mark MainActivityViewModel as injectable; it creates the instance manually [on line 136](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/MainActivity.kt#L136) as you do in the code you posted here. Either you should construct the instance or Dagger should, but not both. (Dagger is occasionally useful to populate `@Inject` fields on an existing instance, but you don't do that here.) So in any case you can drop the `@Inject` annotation and Dagger will stop worrying about it.